# Defining a counter equal to \@enumdepth

Tags: beamer, enumerate, counters

I need a counter that returns my enumerate level.      The following code works.    But there are two problems.     First I want it to work for the `beamer` class, but when I uncomment the first line and comment out the second line, the code throws an error.      Second I want a counter, not a value, which is why I have the line `\setcounter{depthCtr}{\depthLevel}` command after I've retrieved the level using `depthLevel`.     Obviously, I want to avoid this circuitous method and construct a macro that returns the counter directly.    But my commented out construction `\depthMacro` throws an error.    Could somebody please explain how to construct `\depthMacro` correctly, and how to make it work with the `beamer` class?

```
%\documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{depthCtr}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\depthLevel}{\the\@enumdepth}
\makeatother

%\makeatletter
%\newcommand{depthMacro}{
%   \setcounter{depthCtr}{\the\@enumdepth}
%   \thedepthCtr}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is the base level \depthLevel
\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is the level  \depthLevel
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item This is the level  \depthLevel
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item This is the level  \depthLevel
            \setcounter{depthCtr}{\depthLevel}
            \item This is the level \thedepthCtr
%           \item This is the level  \depthMacro
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're approach works if you use `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}`, i.e. use the `enumerate` environment in a `frame` environment

Comment: Can you give a bit more background information? For what purpose do you need the enumerate level?

Comment: Please see my response to @David_Carlisle below.   He asked the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears what you are looking for is simply LaTeX's own `\@listdepth`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcounter{depthCtr}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\depthLevel}{\the\@enumdepth}
\let\beamer@cramped\relax% just because
\let\c@depthCtr\@enumdepth % make a latex counter version

% HERE!
\newcommand{\mybetterdepthLevel}{\the\@listdepth}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
This is the base level \depthLevel

This is the base level \thedepthCtr

This is the base level \mybetterdepthLevel

\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is the level  \depthLevel
    \item This is the level  \thedepthCtr
    \item Yes, this is the level  \mybetterdepthLevel
    \begin{itemize}
        \item This is the level  \depthLevel
        \item This is the level  \thedepthCtr
        \item No! this is in fact the level  \mybetterdepthLevel
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item This is the level  \depthLevel
            \item This is the level  \thedepthCtr
            \item No! this is in fact the level  \mybetterdepthLevel
            \item Can't go deeper :-( (too deeply nested error)
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really really want a LaTeX counter, just use

```
% HERE!
\let\c@mylistdepth\@listdepth
\newcommand{\mybetterdepthLevel}{\arabic{mylistdepth}}
```

or perhaps rather

```
\let\c@mylistdepth\@listdepth
\newcommand{\themylistdepth}{\the\value{mylistdepth}}
\newcommand{\mybetterdepthLevel}{\themylistdepth}
```

so that you can really use `mylistdepth` as a full LaTeX counter.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcounter{depthCtr}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\depthLevel}{\the\@enumdepth}
\let\beamer@cramped\relax% just because
\let\c@depthCtr\@enumdepth % make a latex counter version
\makeatother



\begin{document}
This is the base level \depthLevel

This is the base level \thedepthCtr

\begin{enumerate}
    \item This is the level  \depthLevel
    \item This is the level  \thedepthCtr
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item This is the level  \depthLevel
        \item This is the level  \thedepthCtr
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item This is the level  \depthLevel
            \item This is the level  \thedepthCtr
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @David_Carlisle.    I should have generalized my MWE the first time around.   I want the counter to work with a mixture of itemize and enumerate levels, so somehow I have to add \@enumdepth to \@itemdepth to get the right answer.  But I can't seem to manage integer arithmetic.    Could you tell me how I would do that?    Sorry for not asking the first time around.

Comment: @LeoSimon it's not at all clear why you need a latex counter version, as opposed to say `\makeatletter\def\zzz{\numexpr\@enumdepth+\@itemdepth\relax}`   then use  `\the\zzz` to print the value ir `\ifnum\zzz=6 I'm getting too deep\fi`  in the document

Comment: my original intent was to pass the counter as an optional <> argument to `\hypertarget` identifying the level that I was at, but this turned out to be misguided.   I'm now using an ugly \ifthenelse construction which most likely didn't need a counter.     But it was a learning experience!